# iOS - Promo Codes not working when generated?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, storekit, apple-developer-account

I'm generating offer codes for my app (1 year free). I've generated 500 brand new redemption codes/links, and for some reason none of them work. Navigating to one of the code links just tells me it's expired. I have had a couple people try them and no matter how many times I generate a fresh set, the user gets a code expired message.

Why is this happening? Has anyone experienced this? I've generated working codes before, this issue has just started occurring for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible cause of this problem. Happened to me a short while ago. I wanted to give promo codes to customers that would give them a free year of the app subscription. However when I generated the code I generated the wrong type of code. I should have generated a "In-App Purchase Promo Codes" but instead I generated a "app promo code". The customer would enter the promo code on their iPhone and when they went to restore the purchase it just said the subscription was expired.